# Element does not vertically stick on the middle of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to create a modal popup using JQuery, but somehow I am stuck at the point where I can't properly centralized my element (The keypoint being the element is always centralized regardless of your screen resolution). The below jsfiddle written is the code I want the element to be vertically centralized (as horizontally centralized can be done using CSS.)

HTML: 
    Testing

CSS:

```
.ex_event_frame {
    left: 39px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #2e3030;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    -box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    border: 8px solid #105f6b;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    var offset = 0,
        viewportHeight = $(window).height(),
        $myDialog = $('#ev-entry');
    $myDialog.css('top', (offset + (viewportHeight / 2)) - ($myDialog.Height() / 2));
});
```

Here the fiddle I've created: http://jsfiddle.net/8v9k9/2/

I'm running out of ideas and hopefully I will be able to  hear answers as soon as possible. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set it to `top: 50%` in your CSS then set the margin top to a negative of element.height/2 using jQuery. Or, if your height is fixed, just set it to `margin-top: -150px` directly in your CSS.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see any changes in it though...am I missing something here?

Comment: My bad, didn't fork the fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/z9z5U/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/btFG3/)

```
$(function () {
    $(window).resize(function(){
    var offset = 0,
        viewportHeight = $(window).height(),
        $myDialog = $('#ev-entry');
    console.log(viewportHeight + " "+$myDialog.height() )
    $myDialog.css('top', (offset + (viewportHeight / 2)) - ($myDialog.height() / 2));
    }).resize();
});
```

---

- It's `.height()` instead of `.Height()`
- It's inside `$(window).resize()` so it adjusts on resize as well

Comment: I see! Tested and it works! Thank you very much! However I want to know why console.log is actually used? I thought it is mainly used for debugging?

Comment: Oh you're right, was actually debugging with console.log and forgot to remove them. Alerts are too annoying imo :D

Answer (score 0):

If you need to center an absolute position element you need to do this little trick, requires no jQuery.

The changed css:

```
.ex_event_frame {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    left: 50%; /* Changed CSS */
    top: 50%; /* Changed CSS */
    margin-left: -150px; /* Changed CSS - Change to half of the elements width */
    margin-top: -150px; /* Changed CSS - Change to half of the elements height */
    overflow: auto;
    background: #2e3030;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    -box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    border: 8px solid #105f6b;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: [Demo - remove /show in url to view code](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/8v9k9/4/show/)