# The "Vertically stick on the middle screen" bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a follow up question on "[Element does not vertically stick on the middle of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143601/element-does-not-vertically-stick-on-the-middle-of-the-screen)"

I've tried to use the JS code as solved before and it worked successfully initially, but after a few updates the code suddenly turned wonky and pushes the modal popup way down instead of sticking at the middle of the screen.

I suspect that the code has .resize property in it but somehow the code was left "incomplete". Any help regarding how to solve this issue and make window stay absolutely centered is appreciated.

Link here in case a demo is needed: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8v9k9/15/)

Code (JQuery/JavaScript)

```
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var offset = 0,
        viewportHeight = $(window).height(),
        $myDialog = $('.reveal-modal');
        $myDialog.css('top', (offset + (viewportHeight / 2)) - ($myDialog.height() / 2));
    }).resize();
});
```

Comment: You seem to have combined both answers from that other question.  You have to pick just one.  Also, jquery doesn't work unless you include it.  There's a dropdown in the top left corner of jsfiddle to pick your framework

Comment: The problem is that I created that fiddle in order to image the current problem I have right now. Due to company purposes I cannot show the real website with the problem. But if you look at the fiddle, the end output is exactly the problem I'm facing right now: the modal popup got pushed downwards.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations are incorrect, you must have `margin-top:` as `-200px` instead of `-150px`.

```
...
width: 300px;
height: 400px;
margin-left: -150px; // Half the width (negative)
margin-top: -200px; // Half the height (negative)
...
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/8v9k9/22/)

Comment: And the javascript should be removed.  It is currently blowing up due to the missing jquery include.  If jquery were properly included it would be even worse as the javascript would throw it all off.

Comment: @JamesMontagne you are completely right! I didn't even look at the JavaScript! I removed it now.